# \includepdf only includes a blank page with file name instead of the actual document

Tags: pdfpages

I'm trying to use includepdf to insert an external document into my thesis. I'm using Texlive in Linux, I have the package pdfpages installed properly. I'm compiling the document with pdflatex.

```
....
\RequirePackage{pdfpages} 
....  
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1]{assignment.pdf}
\include{chap-introduction}
\include{chap-problem-specification}
....
```

I don't get the "assignment.pdf" included. Instead, I only get an empty page with the text "assignment.pdf". The compilation is successfull, there is no pdfpages-related warning or error in the logs. I tried it with few different files, but no success. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have the option `draft` activated in the package or class?

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have expected that the draft flag can be the cause.

Comment: You should use `\usepackage{pdfpages}` in your preamble. And maybe in this case, `\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}` should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `draft` option, no pictures are included. Only the filename of the image is printed. `pdfpages` simply includes the pdf-pages as pagesized images and is also effected by the option.